# Chrome on android nexus issue

Tags: android, google-chrome

Hi I have the following jQuery that is working across all desktop browsers (by adding the class the text in the span is changed by the js call to the 3rd party site) and most mobile devices except for Chrome on Android Nexus. Does anyone know why?

```
$(function() {
alert(1);
var foundinspan = $('span:contains("0800 111 222")');
foundinspan.addClass("test11111");
var adiInit ="3526";
var adiFunc = null;
(function() {
   var adiSrc = document.createElement("script"); adiSrc.type = "text/javascript";
   adiSrc.async = true;
   adiSrc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://")
                 + "static.xxxxx.com/static/scripts/xxxx.xxx.min.js";
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(adiSrc, s);
   alert(2);
 })();
});
```

Both alerts fire so it completes. Firefox on Android Nexus works OK?

Comment: Don't know if this is the reason, probably not, but where you have aler(1) just under the $(function(), is that a type, should it not be alert(1).

Comment: sorry typo, problem still there! both alerts fire ok, seem sto work on every browser/platform except chrome/nexus android

Comment: In that case I have no idea sorry, I don't know much about how it works but have you tried enabling the chrome debugger and stepping through it and see what it does or doesn't do.

Comment: I've pasted your code into http://jsbin.com/azuyik/1 - both alerts fire on Chrome for Android. The cause of the issue must be dependant on something else, can you provide a full example of the issue that fails on Chrome?

Comment: What happens when it fails for you -- what can you see from the Chrome Dev Tools? Can you see the script element? Couple of suggestions: does removing `adiSrc.async = true;` make a difference, and does `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];` actually return a script element?